# ElasticSearch _source field in golang

Tags: go, elasticsearch, opensearch

I am implementing a golang API which will search in elastic search index and retrieve results. The index contains huge nested fields. To optimise the search, I want to use a query like

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "_source": ["nested_object.nested_field"], 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field": "dummy object"
    }
  }
}
```

I am not able to find implementations of this `_source` field in golang. I am using the `oliviere/elastic/v7` package. Can someone help me in implementing this??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add FetchSourceContext to your query. Something like that:

```
fetchContext := elastic.NewFetchSourceContext(true)
fetchContext = fetchContext.Include(fieldsToFetch...)

SearchResult, err := r.es.Search().
    Index(r.index).
    Query(Query),
    ).
    FetchSourceContext(fetchContext).
    Do(ctx)
```